# What does 'haply' mean in Keats's 'Ode to a Nightingale'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, poetry, nineteenth-century-english

The following line occurs in Keats's poem 'Ode to a Nightingale':

> And haply the Queen-Moon is on her throne

It seems to me that 'haply' means either, as Merriam-Webster says, 'by chance', or, possibly, the same as 'happily'. So, which is it?

Comment: I don't think your _pards_ questions should have been closed here, but it definitely would have stayed open on [Literature.SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/). You may consider posting your poetry questions there, as they may garner you deeper, more literature-oriented answers than here.

Comment: Not in Cambridge Dictionary but I would say 'haply' means 'as it happens' or 'by happenstance'. So I go with M-W. The moon is neither happy nor unhappy but goes where nature/physics dictates. The chance being the *timing* of the event – on that night the moon was there.

Comment: @Heartspring Thanks for the tip. I'll bear that in mind.

Comment: @Weather Vane True, but irrelevant: Poets attribute emotions to anything and everything, and have no hesitation contradicting scientific facts (e.g., deathless birds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Happy* is used twice in the poem's first stanza, and *happily* in that position could also be read as an adjective describing the Queen's mood; this fits the mood of the poem. Had Keats meant *hap'ly*, however, he would have written the contraction, as he does with *fam'd* in the last stanza. Therefore the text supports that a double reading intended -- perhaps Keats is being a little fey himself?

Further, *haply* (i.e., "by chance") can be read as something more like "luckily," putting it very close to one meaning of *happily*.

Comment: How do you get a read of *luckily* in this context?

Answer (score 2):

From the *OED*:

> **haply** *adverb*
>  Now *archaic* and *poetic*.
> *(a)* Perhaps, possibly; maybe. Cf. **mayhap** *adv.* *(b)* By chance, by accident; (also) luckily, fortunately (contextually:
> unfortunately).
>  <sub>Source: [*Oxford English
> Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

By the way, one of the citations, at 1703, uses an apostrophe: *Hap’ly I stole unheeded to her Chamber*. There it means not *happily* but *luckily*.

In any case, in Keats’s line, it seems *haply* means *maybe*:

> And **haply** the Queen-Moon is on her throne,
>  Cluster'd around by all
> her starry Fays;
>  But here there is no light...
>
> And **maybe** the Queen-Moon is on her throne,
>   surrounded by her
> fairy stars;
>   But here there is no light...

As in, the moon and stars may be out, but it’s dark in the forest.